# Computing average of repeated measures before linear regression

Tags: repeated-measures

Suppose I have a repeated measures dataset where multiple measures of a continuous outcome are taken on each subject in the dataset. How would one perform linear regression? Does it make sense to first compute the average of all outcomes per subject and then run the regression? I know mixed-effects models or GEEs are more appropriate particularly if the ICC is high - but let's ignore those models and focus on linear regression...

If anyone knows what would be appropriate please chime.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the set up of the problem and give more details? To me, "Suppose I have a repeated measures dataset where multiple measures of a continuous outcome are taken on each subject in the dataset. How would one perform linear regression? ", this is unclear. What are your features, what is your response?

Comment: What did you want me to clarify?...I am confused because I think the set-up as described is quite clear.

Comment: What are your repeated measures? Are they high dimensional? What are your responses? Are they the same for each measure (i.e, is it a multiple instance regression setting)?

Comment: Thanks Tom. Yes - the data is high dimensional (which I assume means the number of repeated measures is greater than the number of observations). I am not quite sure what you mean by multiple instance regression.

Comment: See [Linear regression with multiple y values per x and their arithmetic means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/353258/10479). Near duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Repeated Measures Correlation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5383908/pdf/fpsyg-08-00456.pdf). There you can see when it comes for repeated measures and linear regression

> one common solution is to average the repeated measures data for each participant prior to performing the correlation.

That means, averaging repeated measures (as you proposed) to resolve the issue of non-independence in the errors is not *wrong* but it can

> produce misleading results if there are meaningful individual differences.

Despite of the solution proposed by the cited article, one can also use [panel linear models](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plmPackage.html) (i.e. adjusting for the subject effect) which can be seen as the econometric analogon to linear mixed-effects models.

Analog informations are provided in [Correlation Coefficients for a Study with Repeated Measures](https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/cmmm/2020/7398324.pdf)