Proof that regression coefficients are identical for averages over treatments data and raw data
The topic is somewhat related to this question.
Let's say  Experiment with treatments T0, T1, T2 with four repetitions for each and a response $y = (y_{0, 1}, y_{0, 2}, ..., y_{2, 4})$, one observetion for each experimental unit.
If I fit a regression model, let's say $y = \beta x + \epsilon$ I should get the same coefficient $\hat{\beta}$ as if I use data averaged by treatments:
$y^* = (\bar{y_{0, \cdot}},\bar{y_{1, \cdot}}, \bar{y_{2, \cdot}})$.
Of course, no standard error of the parameters can be estimated and statistical tests are no longer possible. My question only regards the fit.
My attempt
The OLS solution is $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$ for a linear regression model. I want to show that $\hat{\beta}^* = (X'^*X^\*)^{-1}X'^\*y^\*$ .
with equal sized groups of size $n$ and
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
the "average response" $y^* = \frac{1}{n}A'y$ can be expressed, as well as $X^* = \frac{1}{n}A'X$.
I get
$$\hat{\beta}^* =  \left(\left(\frac{1}{n}A'X\right)'\frac{1}{n}A'X\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}A'X\right)'\frac{1}{n}A'y$$
resolving to
$$(X'AA'X)^{-1}X'AA'y $$
Can $AA'$ be cancelled out somehow or did I take a wrong turn already?
Simple R-code to illustrate my point:
library(dplyr)

x <- c(10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 40, 40, 40, 40)
y <- 10 + 5* x -0.01*x**2 + rnorm(12, 0, x)
df <- data.frame(
  x = x, 
  y = y, 
  block = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4)
)

plot(x, y)

m1 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), data = df)
coef(m1)

p1 <- predict(m1, newdata = data.frame(x = 0:50))
lines(0:50, p1)

df2 <- df %>% summarise(x = mean(x), y = mean(y), .by = block)

points(df2$x, df2$y, col = "red", pch = 3)

m2 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), data = df2)
coef(m2)

p2 <- predict(m2, newdata = data.frame(x = 0:50))
lines(0:50, p2, col = "blue")


See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/353258/10479.

When the numbers of replicates vary, the solution is weighted least squares.
